# "Good night", "sleep well", which one is more formal, which one is more intimate?

Tags: phrases, formality, business-language, greetings

"Good night", "sleep well",
which one is more formal, which one is more intimate?

Comment: I'd call "sleep well" relatively intimate, and certainly not formal.  But "good night" is not formal either and can be used in both formal and informal discourse.

Comment: @cruthers The questioner is asking which is the _more_ formal rather than which is formal and which is intimate. I would say, as you have, that "sleep well" is always relatively intimate but that "good night" although it can be used in informal settings (it would be appropriate for a romantic partner to say "good night darling" or for a parent to say "good night" to a child for example) it can be used formally. It would be appropriate for a security man to say "good night, ma'm" as a senior executive was leaving an office block. For that man to say "Sleep well ma'm" would be odd, at least.

Answer (score 2):

"Sleep well" would be more intimate.

While "Good night" can be used in both formal and informal settings, it is not as personal as "sleep well".

If you are not sure of the formality of a situation, preferably use "good night".